# Bringing up SoftKeyboard on android

Tags: android

I want to pop up the software keyboard when the user presses the search hardware search key.

At the moment I use the following function with doesn't seem to work for the search key but which does work for the back key:
The logging doesn't get even tiggered through the search key.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Log.v(TAG, "On back key press");
            renderPrevious();

        return false;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
            Log.v(TAG, "On search key press");
            this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

        return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I have no text field but want to handle the input directly myself if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

this method `setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)` doesnt wakeup the keyboard. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setSoftInputMode(int)). More to know about it check this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.html). hope it helps

Edit:

try this [showSoftInput method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html#showSoftInput(int,android.os.ResultReceiver))

Comment: The example link goes to software that implements a whole keyboard to replace the default keyboard, it's not about simply using a soft keyboard in a app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
 InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-set-focus-and-show-soft.html

"When experimenting I was not actually getting what I wanted until I realized I should have an emulator device with no hardware keyboard:"